# Publishing failed error due to "CAST()" in post

Tags: sql, json

When updating a post about the SQL functions CAST and CONVERT, the post fails to update because I use parentheses after the word "CAST" (ie CAST()). It does not happen if I add parentheses after CONVERT (ie CONVERT()). See picture below.

When I remove the parentheses from CAST(), the post saves and publishes without a problem. Also, if I add a space between CAST and (), the post saves okay(ie CAST ()).

I am convinced this is the problem since I added and saved a .htaccess file with the wordpress-recommended code on their website and still ran into the error. I didn't mess around with permalinks, since I wanted to find a less risky solution.

Has anyone else ran into a similar issue? Any tips?

Edit: I should mention that all plugins were deactivated before posting this question. Thanks to Caleb for the suggestion to include relevant debug.log errors. See most recent line added to the log when I try to update the site with "CAST()" in title or body of the post:

```
[19-Jul-2023 22:31:14 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property Sinatra::$options is deprecated in /home2/herculj1/public_html/wp-content/themes/sinatra/functions.php on line 140
[19-Jul-2023 22:31:14 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property Sinatra::$fonts is deprecated in /home2/herculj1/public_html/wp-content/themes/sinatra/functions.php on line 141
[19-Jul-2023 22:31:14 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property Sinatra::$icons is deprecated in /home2/herculj1/public_html/wp-content/themes/sinatra/functions.php on line 142
[19-Jul-2023 22:31:14 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property Sinatra::$customizer is deprecated in /home2/herculj1/public_html/wp-content/themes/sinatra/functions.php on line 143
[19-Jul-2023 22:31:14 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Creation of dynamic property Sinatra::$admin is deprecated in /home2/herculj1/public_html/wp-content/themes/sinatra/functions.php on line 146
```

[[image: CAST() with parentheses causes error.]]

Comment: Please check your [error log](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/debugging-in-wordpress/) and edit your question to include any relevant errors.

Comment: Is that screenshot showing the post's title (ie, the first line in the editor) or is is a subheading in the post content? (Not that there should be an issue with `CAST()` in either case, but I'm curious.) Also: Are you using any plugins on the site? Does the issue go away if you turn them all off?

Comment: @Caleb: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated my question with the error. PatJ: Yes that is correct, it is the post's title, and the plugins were ALL deactivated as part of the debugging process. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: Hmm deprecations shouldn't cause a problem. I'll test this by tomorrow.

Comment: Tested and did not have an issue. What is your theme? Try one of the WordPress built ones (Twenty*).

Comment: I had Sinatra activated, and now activated Twenty Twenty-Three and still have the same issue, unfortunately. I now a slightly different error: PHP Deprecated: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($search) of type array|string is deprecated in /home2/herculj1/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/endurance-page-cache.php on line 862.

Comment: If there's nothing in the PHP error log, it's likely an issue on the server caused by something like `mod_security` blocking the request because the contents look suspicious. I suggest talking to your host about the issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I ended up using Elementor as my workaround. The source of the error is still mysterious, but that's where I'll leave this topic for now.